# Python multiprocessing: RuntimeError: "Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am aware of multiprocessing.Manager() and how it can be used to create shared objects. In particular, queues which can be shared among workers. There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217002/how-do-you-pass-a-queue-reference-to-a-function-managed-by-pool-map-async), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609595/python-multiprocessing-with-an-updating-queue-and-an-output-queue).

However, these links don't mention why we can use inheritance for sharing between processes. As I understand, a queue can still only be copied in this case.

Comment: Are you thinking of the wrong meaning of "inheritance"? They're talking about processes inheriting queues from the process that spawns them, not `class Child(Parent)` OOP inheritance.

Comment: pls see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55577761/429476

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Queue` implementation in python relies on a system `pipe` to transmit the data from one process to another and some `semaphores` to protect the read and write on this `pipe`.

The `pipe` is handled as an open file in the process and can only be shared with a subprocess at spawning time, because of OS constraints.
The `semaphores` are also treated as files that should only be shared at spawning time, at least in UNIX based system, for early version of python.

As these 2 sub objects cannot be shared in general, the `Queue` cannot be pickled and sent to a subprocess once it has been started.

However, for some OS and recent version of python, it is possible to share the `Connection` and to create sharable `Semaphore`. Thus, you could in theory create your own `Queue` that can be shared between processes. But it involves a lot of hacks and might not be very secured.

Comment: For future readers, you can find a code example for the above approach to make queues, locks, etc. picklable here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247561/16310741