# multiprocessing.Queue as arg to pool worker aborts execution of worker

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm actually finding it hard to believe that I've run into the issue I have, it seems like it would be a big bug in the python multiprocessing module... Anyways the problem I've run into is that whenever I pass a multiprocessing.Queue to a multiprocessing.Pool worker as an argument the pool worker never executes its code. I've been able to reproduce this bug even on a very simple test that is a slightly modified version of example code found in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Here is the original version of the example code for Queues:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())  # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

Here is my modified version of the example code for Queues:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Pool(1)
    p.apply_async(f,args=(q,))
    print(q.get()) # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

All I've done is make p a process pool of size 1 instead of a multiprocessing.Process object and the result is that the code hangs on the print statement forever because nothing was ever written to the Queue! Of course I tested this in its original form and it works fine. My OS is windows 10 and my python version is 3.5.x, anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Update: Still no idea why this example code works with a multiprocessing.Process and not a multiprocessing.Pool but I found a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217002/how-do-you-pass-a-queue-reference-to-a-function-managed-by-pool-map-async) I'm content with (Alex Martelli's answer). Apparently you can just make a global list of multiprocessing.Queues and pass each process and index to use, I'm going to avoid using a managed queue because they are slower. Thanks Guest for showing me the link.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039159/3767239), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217002/3767239), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9908781/3767239), [#4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42659752/3767239), [#5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558333/3767239). It seems the reason is that the `Queue` instance cannot be pickled. However I don't understand why this deadlocks the underlying in-queue of the process. Using `Ctrl+C` with pool size of 2 revealed that it was stuck at `task = inqueue.get()` where it would request the target function. That's a bit puzzling.

Comment: Note that with asynchronous programming you don't need to manually deal with result queues - `apply_async` returns a [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) instance which can be used to get the result: `result.get()`. This uses an underlying result (out-) queue and so you simply need to `return` in your target function. Also if you use `result.get()` and you passed a `Queue` instance as an argument to the target function it will raise a `RuntimeError`. However I'm curious why this doesn't happen for your example.

Comment: See my comment to your answer. My goal isn't a "result queue" this is just a trivial example. I need a queue that is continually written to and processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

When you call [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) it returns a [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object and leaves the workload distribution to a separate thread (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184127/3767239)). This thread encounters the problem that the [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) object can't be [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and therefore the requested work can't be distributed (and eventually executed). We can see this by calling [`AsyncResult.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get):

```
r = p.apply_async(f,args=(q,))
r.get()
```

which raises a `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

However this `RuntimeError` is only raised in the main thread once you request the result because it actually occurred in a different thread (and thus needs a way to be transmitted).

So what happens when you do

```
p.apply_async(f,args=(q,))
```

is that the target function `f` is never invoked because one of it's arguments (`q`) can't be pickled. Therefore `q` never receives an item and remains empty and for that reason the call to `q.get` in the main thread blocks forever.

## Solution

With `apply_async` you don't have to manage the result queues manually but they are readily provided to you in form of [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) objects. So you can modify the code to simply return from the target function:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def f():
    return [42, None, 'hello']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Pool(1)
    result = p.apply_async(f)
    print(result.get())
```

Comment: Interesting but I don't see how the code works when you just use a multiprocessing.Process instead of a multiprocessing.Pool they both create new processes so wouldn't the Queue need to be pickled for both methods? Also using the AsyncResult workaround isn't really viable for me because I need a bunch of worker Processes that are continually writing to a Queue that is then read and processed by another worker Process.

Comment: @profPlum For those questions I'd like to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184127/3767239). The essence is that the `Pool` starts the processes right away while the `Process` gets started after it received the `Queue` instance (no pickling required here, the process is not yet running). You can use [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)s to share objects between processes or use the `initializer` and `initargs` keyword arguments of [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Comment: ah ok not really sure why the fact that the process is already running requires pickling but with that explanation and info about the initializer and initargs I'll accept your answer

Comment: @profPlum It's due to the way that information is shared between processes. On Unix-like systems they use sockets for that purpose and in order to send a (Python) object through a socket it gets pickled. The `Process` instance in Python will spawn off a system process when started, so prior to this you can share Python objects as usual with that instance. But for sharing with a running process they have to use the OS' way for inter-process communication.

Comment: I see, thanks for the more detailed explanation makes more sense now