# `apply_async` silences "shared queue errors"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Consider the following example:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def work(*args):
    print('work')
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    pool = Pool(1)
    result = pool.apply_async(work, args=(queue,))
    print(result.get())
```

This raises the following `RuntimeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(result.get())
  [...]
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

But interestingly the exception is only raised when I try to `get` the result, not when the "sharing" happens. Commenting the corresponding line silences the error while I actually *did share* the queue (and `work` is never executed!).

**So here goes my question:** Why is this exception only raised when the result is requested, and not when the `apply_async` method is invoked even though the error seems to be recognized because the target `work` function is never called?

It looks like the exception occurs in a different process and can only be made available to the main process when inter-process communication is performed in form of requesting the result. Then, however, I'd like to know why such checks are not performed *before* dispatching to the other process.
(If I used the queue in both `work` and the main process for communication then this would (silently) introduce a deadlock.)

---

Python version is 3.5.2.

---

I have read the following questions:

- [Sharing many queues among processes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039159/3767239)
- [How do you pass a Queue reference to a function managed by pool.map_async()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217002/3767239)
- [Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9908781/3767239)
- [Python multiprocessing: RuntimeError: “Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42659752/3767239)
- [Python sharing a lock between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558333/3767239)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior results from the design of the `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Internally, when you call `apply_async`, you put your job in the `Pool` call queue and then get back a `AsyncResult` object, which allow you to retrieve your computation result using get.
Another thread is then in charge of pickling your work. In this thread, the `RuntimeError` happens but you already returned from the call to `async_apply`. Thus, it sets the results in `AsyncResult` as the exception, which is raised when you call `get`.

This behavior using some kind of future results is better understood when you try using [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), which have explicit future objects and, IMO, a better design to handle failures, has you can query the future object for failure without calling the `get` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question though. If `Queue` objects cannot be shared among processes via arguments why are we allowed to do exactly this with a `multiprocessing.Process` object (see [this documentation example -> Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes))? This doesn't raise a `RuntimeError` and works fine, so where is the difference? The arguments must be transferred to the other process as well, as it is the case for the `Pool`. What about pickling here?

Comment: In the `Pool`, the process are spawn when you instanciate it. Thus, when you call `apply_async`, the `Process` are already started. You can pass a `Queue` in the `Pool` using the arguments `initializer` and `initargs` to declare a global `Queue` in the child processes I think.

Comment: You can also declare the `Queue` as a global attribute of your module, to avoid messing with `initializer`. `pickle` should be able to handle this case I think.